# Three.js OBJLoader does not load obj file

Tags: three.js

I am trying to load a obj file using OBJloader.js
I am trying to load "plane.obj" file which exists inside the same folder where the html files exists and "OBJLoader.js" also exists in the same folder.

Page doesn't show up anything.

Here is the code :

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); 
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1); 
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00}); 
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); scene.add(cube); camera.position.z = 5; 
function render() { 
    requestAnimationFrame(render); 
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01; 
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01; 
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
}
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'tex.jpg' );
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( 'plane.obj', function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object );
} );
render();
```

Comment: Does the console show any error?

Comment: Can you make sure plane.obj loads with another viewer? Also can you remove the cube from the scene. If plane.obj is too small, it might be falling inside the cube and would require some scale factor.

Comment: Thanks Mrdoob and Gaitat. I checked the console error and its "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.". I think I will have to run this page from server(http://localhost etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by trying to load a resource from the file system. You're probably getting a same origin policy security violation and need to serve up your page and resources from the same protocol, domain and port. There are a few easy ways to do this - I use a simple http server app via Node JS. check out [How to run things locally](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out for me to be caused by the absence of light in the scene. Also, improper camera position may also lead to "invisible" OBJ models. Try adding the following lines:

```
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambientLight);
```